# Mongoose and router files

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

My folder structure is the following:

```
bin/
  www
models/
  myMongooseModel.js
public/
  ...
routes/
  index.js
  anotherroute.js
views/
  ...
app.js
package.json
```

In the file `app.js`, I have some settings (`app.set` and `app.use` commands). In the `routes/` directory, there are files for the routes, one file for each. In those files, I handle the requests from the users. The file `bin/www.js` sets up the server.

The question is the following: How do I integrate Mongoose in this setup, i.e., where should I initialize it and what should I include in the router files?

Is this the best way?

`db.js`:

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('connected');
});
```

`index.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MyModel = mongoose.model('myMongooseModel');
// do something with MyModel
```

How do I avoid that requests are made before the db connection is set up?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to add some promises! Presumably, somewhere in your app.js you're initializing the app, giving it a port, and telling it to start accepting traffic. Before that step, you can use a thenable to wait for the established connection to begin. Ideally, this logic is modularized into its own 'createConnection.js'.

It might look something like:

```
// app.js
const app = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectPromise = mongoose.connect('myuri');
connectPromise.then(() => app.listen(3000))
```

Be sure to take a look at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect.

Comment: What does the syntax "() => app.listen(3000)" mean? Does it work in plain JS or NodeJS or is it something special?

Comment: It's part of the [ES6 specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It's commonly available in Node 4.x and up.